# How would I build a Tsuchigumo in D&D 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters

I need help building a monster(s). I want a Tsuchigumo from [Japanese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsuchigumo) folklore. I'm aiming for the under ground race/spider shapeshifter cross-blend, having these be a community from the Feywild that live in the nearby mountains and can be a hindrance (and maybe friends). I'm probably going to try to build a few different roles.  I'm looking to make them appropriate for 3-5 level players.

A range of level 5 to 8 would be appreciated..

Comment: Here's a good Noh reference http://www.the-noh.com/en/plays/data/program_002.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, Here's my take on it. I'm not terribly familure with the myth but I think it covers the bases. (ps my math is not perfect as im just doing it by hand so please consider this an example not the definitive answer to what someone could do with it).

### Tsuchigumo Lurker        Level 4 Lurker

Medium Aberrant Humanoid         Xp 175

Init +8  Sense Perception +9, Darkvision
Hps 42; Bloodied 21
Ac 18, Fort 16, Ref 18, Will 14
Speed 5

**Parasitic Illusion**

The Lurker can take part in a Tsuchigumo Queen's Illusion Power appearing as a minor actor or figure within the illussion. The Lurker is not invisible, but appears as a non threatening humanoid.

### Spider Claws

Melee Basic, Standard, At- Will
+9 vs Ac; 1d6+4 Damage and 2 ongoing poison damage.

Special: If the target gives combat advantage this power deals ongoing 5 poison damage.
Special: If the target is affected by the Tsuchigumo Queen's Illusion Power the Lurker may use this power. It deals no damage and requires no attack roll and inflicts ongoing 2 poison damage.

### Tsuchigumo Queen        Level 4 Solo

Large Aberrant Beast         Xp 700

Init +2  Sense Perception +10, Darkvision
Hps 280; Bloodied 140
Ac 16, Fort 20, Ref 14, Will 18
Speed 2

**Web Illusion**

The Tsuchigumo Queen can create a cunning illusion from nothing more than cobwebs and malice. The Queen can create the appearance of people, places, buildings and more within a 1 mile radius from herself. This effect requires 24 hours preparation but lasts until it is detected, or the party succeeds a complexity 2 skill challenge ( 6 successes before 3 failures ). The Key Skills are Insight, Perception and Nature. Doing Damage to a figure in the illussion counts as an auto success. If the Party succeeds the illusion is dropped. If the Party fails, they take ongoing 10 poison Damage and the illusion drops after the end of the Tsuchigumo's Turn.

### Mandibles.

Melee Basic, Standard, At- Will

Make two mandibles attack.

+7 vs Ac; 1d10+4 Damage

Special: If both attacks hit the same target, that target takes 10 ongoing poison damage (save ends).

### Spawning Blow

Immediate Interrupt, Free Action, At-Will

Trigger- The Tsuchigumo Queen is bloodied or reduced to 0 hps.

Effect: The queen spawns four Tsuchigumo Broodlings adjacent to her and then shifts 8 squares, ignoring difficult terrain.

### Tsuchigumo Broodlings         Level 4 minion

Small Aberrant Beasts             Xp 37

Hps 1, a missed attack never damages a minion
Ac 14, Fort 12, Ref 16, Will 12
Speed 7

### Feeding Frenzy

basic attack, standard, at-will

+6 vs Ac, 2 damage and 2 poison damage for every broodling Adjacent to the target (including this one).

Answer (score 2):

You could of course build something very custom, but if you are looking for something quick and tested, you have plenty to work with form MM1.  Ettercap are spider humanoids ranging in level from 4-5.  Throw in a little doppelganger change shape action, and I think your all set.  Even Driders (with a level adjustment) or wererats (with a reflavoring) would do a decent job.

Rather than reinventing the wheel, when I need to create a new race, I just find a group thats already created and reskin them.  I usually use the following formula:

1)Find a group of monster in the level range that I like

2)Change damage types, power effects and size to fit the race I am creating. In your case, maybe change elemental attacks to poison and change debuffs to include more slows and immobilize.

3)Replace previous racial powers (if any) with small signature power I create.  I think this is important to tie the group together.

4)Describe them to you players as you envision them.